# What species of shrimp is "delicate pale colored river shrimp"?

Tags: shrimp

Which is the [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species)? There are YouTube videos how to make [龍井蝦仁](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E9%BE%8D%E4%BA%95%E8%9D%A6%E4%BB%81&client=firefox-b-d&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihncusn5LjAhVpUN8KHQ5dAZsQ_AUIEigD&biw=1536&bih=700).

[Dragon Well Green Tea Shrimp Stir Fry 龍井炒蝦仁 | Chinese Recipes at TheHongKongCookery.com](http://www.thehongkongcookery.com/2017/05/dragon-well-green-tea-shrimp-stir-fry.html)

> Traditionally delicate pale colored **river shrimp** were used for this dish.  As river shrimp are almost impossible to come by these days we used [frozen shrimp](http://amzn.to/2reOt5n).   But let me quantify that statement.  Frozen shrimp sold in Hong Kong is absolutely fresh when frozen and tastes pretty darn close to fresh shrimp.  The Cantonese are famously picky about their shrimp.  But as you know, once shrimp gets not fresh it just don't taste good at all.

[Stir Fried Prawns with Longjing Tea (龙井虾仁) – teavivre](https://www.teavivre.com/info/stir-fried-prawns-with-longjing-tea.html)

> Stir Fried Prawns with Longjing Tea (Longjing Shrimp for short) is a typical dish of Hangzhou cuisine. Just as its name implies, Longjing Shrimp is made by cooking peeled **river prawns** with tender shoots of famous Longjing tea.

Comment: Where are you asking from? The United States? Canada? UK? There are a lot of potential substitutes found in Canada.

Comment: @JCrosby  i live in Canada.

Comment: Check T&T if you live near one, ask in both the seafood and dried goods areas using the chinese names for the shrimp.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia works well as a contextual dictionary in these cases, so I just C+P the chinese name in Wikipedia and it gave me this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longjing_prawns

In that case you should be looking for river prawns (a.k.a. freshwater shrimps, depending on where you live), and a quick search in google gives you this guy: https://www.siamcanadian.com/freshwater-shrimp.html